# How do I edit my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

This is probably a noob question, but I forgot how to edit my profile.

Can anyone help me? There is no visible button for me.

Comment: it certainly could do with some UX improvement. ;/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

[image]

Comment: Is it deliberately hidden? This needs to be easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you click the link in the above post, while logged in, it will take you to the edit page for your profile. I used this to edit a typo in my About Me section.