# Bounty - Does that reward reputation points or will cost my reputation points?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, bounties

I've never used bounty on one of my questions. I've read that I can set a bounty and they will appear prominent.

I should then award the best question.

So, will they (who awarded) get same reputation points as I've set bounty? Will the same reputation points of mine be cut from my account if I award another?

Comment: @curiousdannii Could you please help me. If I award someone any bounty. Will my reputations be cutted from my account?

Comment: @AAShakil it says in the duplicate *"Bounty awards are funded by the personal reputation of the users who offer them."* and *"The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started..."*. So yes, it will.

Comment: If you set a bounty for X reputation, your own reputation is decreased by X. You have _spent X reputation points_ to make the question more visible. You do not get the X reputation points back. Once you award the bounty to someone else, that someone else gets X reputation points.

Comment: @AAShakil, Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can set bounty on **any question** (including someone else's question) to put it in the featured list and it will be slowly bumped up when the bounty (7 days) is almost over. This will make your question be easily viewed and receives more attention.
- When you **set** the bounty, the reputation as equivalent to the bounty will be deducted immediately from your accout and cannot be refunded in any cases. If you don't have enough reputation to start a bounty, you won't be able to even set the bounty.
- When you feel like one of the answers is worthy of your bounty (and your bounty has lasted at least 24 hours) then you can manually award the entire bounty to an answer (once awarded, you cannot cancel the bounty or move it to another answer). Because the reputation from bounty is already deducted when you  **set** the bounty, you won't lost any reputation again from **rewarding** the bounty.
- The answerer of your awarded bounty will receive the entire bounty amount that you have set, without any restrictions from the 200 daily reputation cap. If you don't award your bounty in the 7 days bounty period + 1 day grace period, then **half** of the bounty you have set will be automatically awarded to the highest-scoring answer if it has a score of at least 2 and is not written by the bounty starter (**Exception:** If you start a bounty on **your own question** and accept the answer that would have been awarded half of the bounty as stated above, then the **full** bounty is awarded instead). Again, because you have already lost the reputation when starting the bounty, you won't lose it again.

Comment: This will cost much reputations of mine. Is there probability to increase my reputations also? As people will upvote my question?

Comment: Try looking in the "featured" tab to find bounty questions that you can answer, which will bumped up your reputation a lot. However, being awarded with a bounty is not easy, as I haven't got it once. In exchange, the bounty question when receives more attention, it may receive more upvotes.

Comment: On the other hand, answer upvotes are worth 10 points each, double the value of the question upvotes, also note that answers ifself are upvoted more frequently. Try to answer any possible questions to make up for your lost reputation.

Comment: In fact, here's one incredibly easy bounty currently that both you and I have missed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268743/how-do-i-edit-my-profile

Comment: See also: [Is the bounty system effective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238736/21960)

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí thanks but it's answered